# "Island of isolation" of Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Could anyone please explain the concept of **Island of isolation** of Garbage Collection?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Object A references object B. Object B references object A. Neither object A nor object B is referenced by any other object. That's an island of isolation.

Basically, an island of isolation is a group of objects that reference each other but they are not referenced by any active object in the application. Strictly speaking, even a single unreferenced object is an island of isolation too.

**Edit from Comment:**

```
class A {
   B myB; 
} 
class B { 
   A myA; 
} 

/* later */  
A a = new A(); 
B b = new B();  
a.b = b; 
b.a = a;
```

Comment: This post maybe old. but my question this is question of mine might be kiddie but when you say Object A references object B. Object B references object A. Do you mean SOmething like this A a = B ; B b = a ?

Comment: @user962206 No he means `class A { B myB; } class B { A myA; } /* later */ A a = new A(); B b = new B(); a.b = b; b.a = a;` If you can decipher that... But in all honesty, it's enough to have `class A { B myB; } class B { } B b = new B(); A a = new A(); a.b = b;`

Comment: Code should have been this:
`A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.myB = b;
b.myA = a;`

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: But what happens to the isolated objects anyway? Will they even be removed at some point?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a [good explanation](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-islands-of-isolation-in-garbage-collection/42) of this term. Excerpt:

> - "If an object obj1 is garbage collected, but another object obj2
>     contains a reference to it, then obj2
>     is also eligible for garbage
>     collection"
> - "If object obj2 can access object obj1 that is eligible for garbage
>     collection, then obj2 is also eligible
>     for garbage collection"
>
> This is called "Island of Isolation".
>   An "island of isolation" describes one
>   or more objects have NO references to
>   them from active parts of an
>   application.

Answer (score 9):

The thing to keep in mind is that objects are only collected if they are referenced, either directly or indirectly, from a **GC root object** (threads, current local variables, static variables etc). If two (or more) objects reference each other, but are not referenced from a root, then they are eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, if you understand the concept of Mark and Sweep of Garbage Collection, you'll understand better Island of Isolation too:

- The algorithm starts from the GC roots: main thread, local variables in the       main method, static variables of the main class.
- The algorithm traverses all object references, starting with the GC roots, and marks every object found as alive.
- All of the heap memory that is not occupied by marked objects is reclaimed.  It is simply marked as free, essentially swept free of unused objects.
- If two or more objects are referencing each other but they are not referenced by objects linked with any root, they are in the Island of Isolation, and are swept too.