# What's the term for an isolated set of references?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I know I learnt this on the SCJP syllabus, but it escapes me.

What's the term for a set of objects that refer to each other but are no longer accessible from your program (and are thus eligible for garbage collection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Island of Isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792831/island-of-isolation-of-garbage-collection)

Comment: What has Australia go to do with any of this?

Answer (score 4):

Your objects are **[unreachable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html)** (i.e. they cannot be reached from any current stack frame and can thus be considered to be *garbage*). In the specific case of a set of mutually-referencing objects, these can be said to have **cyclic references**