# would an anonymous class instance who has an implicit reference to the singleton enclosing instance cause memory leak?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, singleton

```
public class Singleton {

  public void processRequest(final List<a> aList) {

      List<b> bList = new AbstractList<b>() {
              b get(int i) {
                   return (b)aList.get(i); 
              }

              int size() {
                   return aList.size();
              }

             ......
      }

  }
```

here an anonymous instance is created with an implicit reference to the enclosing instance. Since the enclosing instance is a singleton that would always exist in JVM, would this prevent the anonymous instance being claimed by GC and cause memory leak?

any help appreciated!

Comment: I assume this is java, added the java tag

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no memory leak here. Objects that refer to non-garbage objects can be collected; it is only objects *referred to by* non-garbage objects that cannot become garbage.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to identify non-garbage objects?

Comment: A non-garbage object is an object that is reachable. A reachable object is an object that can be reached from a GC-root. GC-roots are commonly either references held in the stack memory of a running thread or static state of a loaded class. An object is not reachable when a reference path cannot be constructed between that object and a GC-root.

Answer (score 0):

As Russell said, there is no memory leak here.

An object is eligible to garbage collection when it is not reachable by any thread.

If an object is not referenced by any other object, it is never reachable.
But if A and B are refering to each others, it doesn't mean they are reachable, because both of them can be unreachable from any thread. This is what we call [Island of isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792831/island-of-isolation-of-garbage-collection)

Notice that in some cases, an object reachable from a thread can be collected, when you are not using the normal references (default) but when you use soft or weak references.

> Reachability
>
> Going from strongest to weakest, the different levels of reachability
>   reflect the life cycle of an object. They are operationally defined as
>   follows: An object is strongly reachable if it can be reached by some
>   thread without traversing any reference objects. A newly-created
>   object is strongly reachable by the thread that created it. An object
>   is softly reachable if it is not strongly reachable but can be reached
>   by traversing a soft reference. An object is weakly reachable if it is
>   neither strongly nor softly reachable but can be reached by traversing
>   a weak reference. When the weak references to a weakly-reachable
>   object are cleared, the object becomes eligible for finalization. An
>   object is phantom reachable if it is neither strongly, softly, nor
>   weakly reachable, it has been finalized, and some phantom reference
>   refers to it. Finally, an object is unreachable, and therefore
>   eligible for reclamation, when it is not reachable in any of the above
>   ways.

[Reference package of Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is coming 2 years after the fact, but it came up under my similar question pane when I asked: [Reference to final object in anonymous class constructor a leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669437/reference-to-final-object-in-anonymous-class-constructor-a-leak/26669642?noredirect=1#comment41941986_26669642)

I give a different answer than both @Russel and @Sebestian because they rely on a narrow definition of memory leak.   What leak often means in GC languages, however, is  "keeping a reference thus preventing the GC from collecting it." http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html and that to me seems how OP was using the term.  I think he's asking am I unintendedly keeping this object alive?  Am I preventing the GC from claiming it?

If those are your actual questions, then the answer is yes. aList is an implict field of bList. Holding a reference to bList will prevent aList from being collected, so long as bList is kept alive.