# Reference to final object in anonymous class constructor a leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, anonymous-class

I'm passing a runnable to a service.  The runnable duration may outlive the fragment / activity that passes it.  I'm wondering if the following code snippet would leak the frag object by maintaining a reference inside the runnable?  I realize I can move the whole line containing frag outside of the runnable (like I did with "String key = frag..."), but I'm asking simply to get an understanding of how/when an anonymous class would leak an object.

I'm really not certain.  The runnable only needs frag to determine a variable upon initializing the instance, and it's initialized in-line here.  So in theory, it doesn't need to have any reference to frag after creating the in-line instance.

If I had a reference to frag in the run() function, I would think a leak then would be guaranteed as it would need to keep frag alive to reference it sometime in the future (and frag might very well be gc'd at that point, but for the reference).

```
private static void fg_downloadFile(final FragMyDrive frag, final File file, final Drive drive){

    final String key = frag.getCastedActivity().getKey();

    Runnable rx_downloadFile = new Runnable() {

        Context ServiceContext = frag.getCastedActivity().mService;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            bg_downloadFile(ServiceContext, key, file, drive);
        }
    }; 

    //.... Submit runnable to service...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might know, you must make variables *final* when declaring them outside but using them in an anonymous class. The Java trick here is to *copy* all those variables into implicitly generated instance fields of that anonymous class.

Having said this, it means that there are indeed instance fields (in your runnable) holding copies of all accessed variables of the outer scope. In your example, it would also have a reference to the `FragMyDrive` as you are simply accessing it.

All those objects become eligible for garbage collection at the same time your runnable becomes eligible for garbage collection. That means the reference to your `FragMyDrive` inside your runnable keeps that object alive as long as it is running.

It's always a good idea to narrow down those references to what you really need:

```
private static void fg_downloadFile(final FragMyDrive frag, final File file, final Drive drive){
    final String key = frag.getCastedActivity().getKey();
    final Context context = frag.getCastedActivity().mService;

    Runnable rx_downloadFile = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bg_downloadFile(context, key, file, drive);
        }
    }; 
    //.... Submit runnable to service...
}
```

Here the only (implicitly generated) instance fields are:

```
String key
Context context
File file
Drive drive
```

Comment: Aye, this matches my code actually. Thinking about it now, I think this workaround is always available.  I guess stylistically I just liked having all my class variables actually inside the class definition. A bit of ocd and just plain curiosity on my part for wondering if I could put them there.  I think you're right, and the answer is it would leak if I tried to use objects like frag to initialize the explicitly declared class variables.  The workaround doesn't rely on needing to know that answer though.... making it safe.

Comment: @NameSpace "I just liked having all my class variables actually inside the class definition" => Then make it an explicit class with an explicit constructor. This could well be a `private static final class ...`. You are declaring an anonymous class, and this is always bound to the scope of the method (and thus has access to all final variables). This is _the feature_ of anonymous classes!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your use of the word *inline* correctly but in any case, I don't think anything is leaked here.

Var `final String key` is simply a local reference in your static function `fg_downloadFile()` so it's freed when going out of scope at the end of the function.

The `Runnable` anonymous inner class may still hold a reference (again, not to `frag` but to some sub-property therein) for as long as the `Runnable` thread lives. (More precisely, the compiler actually generates an `implementation` of `Runnable` with a constructor and `final` member variables that copy any implicitly used references to whatever is available in `fg_downloadFile()`'s scope.)

But in any case, once the all code has been executed, all references to (sub-members of) `frag` will be removed and the garbage collector can pick up the trash.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know frag wouldn't leak in the "key = frag" line, it's the serviceContext = frag line i'm wondering about, which is inside the runnable.  Do we both agree that if I referenced frag inside the run() function of the runnable it would definitely be a leak?  Well if the constructor is treated as any old function, then by analogy it would leak...we have to assume the constructor isn't any old function, and the compiler is smart enough to know that an anonymous function's constructor is only need once so that it can discard the frag reference after initializing the instance.

Comment: I agreed that a reference inside the `Runnable` will remain after `fg_downloadFile()` completes, but that's not a leak. As @seelenvirtuose below expresses, the GC will eventually clean up any objects once the `Runnable` is cleaned up. The whole point of having the implicit members inside the `Runnable` "instance" is to make sure the referenced object's live times are aligned with whatever happens in the `run()` function. This comes as close as it gets to what's called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) in C++.

Comment: I realize you're relying on a definition of memory leak where nothing in java is actually a leak.  My concern is actually how long the service keeps the fragment alive, as the task may sit in the service indefinitely (waiting for wifi for example).  In java/android, leak is frequently used to refer to "keeping a reference thus preventing the GC from collecting it."   http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: In that case, the problem would not be with Java or with the reference within the runnable, but with the lifetime of the (pooled) reference.   In any case, if your run function doesn't need all the information that is (implicitly) passed into the runnable, just make sure it isn't passed in. Don't give access to what you don't need. In any case, I don't see what presence or absence of`final` has to do with it.

Comment: The whole question is whether it was implicitly passed to begin with, seeing as an anonymous class is initialized in the same line it's declared, and the objects are only used for initialization.  So is a reference maintained or not?  Sure there's a way we know is safe to write it (I did that with "final String key = frag...", but I'm curious if there's an answer to how the compiler interprets the other way of writing it.

Comment: Okay, I catch your drift. Indeed there is some (undesirable) magic happening in Java's anonymous inner classes - with great power comes great responsibility. Even more so with Java 8's lambdas. I suppose that you should take some extra care to make sure your `Runnable` doesn't (implicitly) reference anything it doesn't need (for it's whole lifetime) in case you expect `bg_downloadFile()` to last very long / indefinitely. I would advocate using a regular class or static inner class to have an explicit interface to what goes in.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Do you have some experience in programming without automatic garbage collection, like Objective C?

But to answer your question, I don't see why it would be a leak.
What I suppose will happen is that the Runnable will keep a reference to frag for it's own use, but at some point in the future, frag will get garbage collected as well once the service does not need it anymore, and hence it's not refering to it.

As garbage collection works, once an object is no longer referenced, it will be subject to garbage collection and deallocated.

Comment: Well I realize (nearly) all memory leaks in gc languages don't quite fit the definition of normal memory leaks.  Here what i'm worried about is the service keeping alive the fragment until the file downloads...the task may sit in a queue for some time, waiting for wifi to be enabled for example.

Comment: I guess the term "normal memory leak" is relative to in which environment you are used to program. Yes, can definitely be the case that the fragment is alive for a while. Are there some other factors that makes this undesirable, large memory use etc?