# how can I know memory leak in java?

Tags: java

I have a class, in this I initialized a frame, but I didn't extend it.
When I run the program and dispose the frame by call the dispose function.
other resources used in this class like String, StringBuffer , int .. etc
can these be collected by JVM , or it is a memory leak ?
should I use null keyword to dispose them one by one?

Comment: Look in to this,it may help you https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java

Comment: There is rarely a memory leak in Java, and certainly not if your using "basic" classes such as what you mention.  The GC will collect them once there are no more references to them; you don't need to "null" them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058991/how-to-monitor-java-memory-usage checkout tools which used to analyse memory utilization. You can trace from that .

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855013/understanding-java-memory-management

Comment: The "best" fit in that wide collection: Garbage collector in java - set an object null

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are not referenced by anything anymore, they will be eaten by the garbage collector when it comes around the next time. If you like, you can also kindly ask the garbage collector to do so soon by calling `System.gc()`

Comment: Beware: You can't depend on `System.gc()` as this call only *suggests* the VM to start the GC. It is not guaranteed to run.

Comment: @QBrute True. That's what I meant by `...kindly ask the garbage collector to...`