# How does Rust handle the "island of isolation" (cycles of references) scenario for reference-counted types?

Tags: rust, reference-counting

How does Rust handle the "island of isolation" scenario for `Rc`s and `Arc`s?

An "island of isolation" is a situation where object `A` contains a pointer to object `B` and object `B` contains a pointer to object `A`, but there are no pointers to either objects anywhere else.

Is Rust smart enough to detect this or does it lead to memory leaks?

Comment: Who calls a reference cycle an "island of isolation"?

Comment: Seems that this is not about a simply reference cycle, but about reference cycle _without external references_ - isolated from the rest of program. The reference cycle by itself isn't bad, it's bad when it gets lost.

Comment: That was not purely a rhetorical question, by the way - I really do want to know where the term "island of isolation" comes from (or if you just made it up)

Comment: @trentcl It seems to be a commonly used term. For instance, check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792831/island-of-isolation-of-garbage-collection

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rust does not have a garbage collector, and it won't detect reference cycles. If your program creates inaccessible reference cycles, they are leaked, and it is up to you to avoid them, e.g. by using [weak references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downgrade), or by not using shared ownership in the first place.

Note that the only way to create a reference cycle is to use both shared ownership and interior mutability.

See also the [chapter on reference cycles in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html).